# Store multi-level

Tags: extjs4

I have the following json :

```
{"service":
{"description":"Export a list of amendments.","id":"504e1bf57e8d2fdd92b6c316cd000b25","name":"AT4AM_AmendmentsList","notes":"Export a list of amendments in a defined format, Word or XML.\r\n\r\n\"keywords\" : [ \"AT4AM\", \"DST\", \"Amendment\", \"Export\", \"Word\", \"XML\" ]","revision":"2-cd375cfd296ba97e934f12794d4930e9","status":"study","type":"entity",
"versions":[{"description":"v1.0 description...","id":"504e1bf57e8d2fdd92b6c316cd0017c0","version":1}]}}
```

I would like to display the list of versions into a grid.

here is my model :

```
Ext.define('XXXX.model.Version', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields : [ {
    name : 'id',
    type : 'string'
}, {
    name : 'description',
    type : 'string'
}, {
    name : 'version',
    type : 'string'
}],
belongsTo: 'XXXX.model.Service',
proxy: {
    type: 'rest',
    id: 'id',
    url : 'http://localhost:8080/xxxxx/services/service',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'versions'
    }
}
```

});

Thanks for help
Medley

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I found :

1 - I added this to the model 'Service'

```
{type: 'hasMany', model: 'XXXX.model.Version', name: 'versions'}
```

2 - I used the configured RestProxy to make a GET request

```
Ext.ModelManager.getModel('XXXX.model.Service').load(serviceId, {
            success: function(service) {
            // Now, it is possible to access to all the versions of a service
            service.versions().each(function(version) {
                    listOfVersions.push(version.data);
    });

}
});
```

Regards
Medley

Answer (score 0):

use `root: 'service.versions'` in your reader's config.

Comment: I tried but still the same. Here is the store :      Ext.define('EPplatosRegistry.store.Versions',{
 extend : 'Ext.data.Store',
    model  : 'EPplatosRegistry.model.Version',
    storeId: 'versionsStore'
});

Comment: Versions can contain several records.